# contenteditable not working after sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

After sorting content editable is not working on left click but on right click it working. WHY?

```
$(function(){

  $("#textTemplate").draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    zIndex: 2500
  });
  $( "#editorDesignView" ).droppable({
        accept: '#textTemplate',
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        var html = '<div id="" style="background: #eee; width: 80%; margin: 10px auto; padding: 10px;"><p contenteditable="true" style="padding: 5px;">Add your text here.</p></div>';
  $(html).appendTo(this).hide().slideDown();

      }
    });
  $('#editorDesignView').sortable();


});
```

[Here is my jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MyTests/pL4Lv6r9/70/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be better if you create a handler for sortable element since its overtake the click event. I created an element with `.draggable-area` and use it on [sortable handle option](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-handle)

```
 $(function(){

  $("#textTemplate").draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    zIndex: 2500,
  });
  $( "#editorDesignView" ).droppable({
        accept: '#textTemplate',
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        var html = '<div id="" style="background: #eee; width: 80%; margin: 10px auto; padding: 10px;"><p contenteditable="true" style="padding: 5px;">Add your text here.</p><div style="padding:20px;" class="draggable-area"></div></div>';
  $(html).appendTo(this).hide().slideDown();

      }
    });
  $('#editorDesignView').sortable({
      handle: '.draggable-area'
  });


});
```

[Updated your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pL4Lv6r9/71/)

Comment: I don`t want to create draggable area. I just want that when I sort the element it sort easily and when I want to edit para I just have to click on it.